# Python transpose pairs of letters scytale cipher

Tags: python, encryption, transpose

So I have some python code that runs the scytale cipher for a string of text,
However I am trying to transpose pairs of letters rather than single letters.

```
plaintext = "abcdefghij"

Current Encoding:
a c e g i 
 b d f h j

Desired Encodeing:
ab  ef  ij
  cd  gh
```

Current Outcome = "acegibdfhj"

Ideal Outcome = "abefijcdgh"

Script:

```
plaintext = "abcdefghij"
key = 2

ciphertext = [''] * key
for column in range(key):
  pointer = column
  while pointer < len(plaintext):
    ciphertext[column] += plaintext[pointer]
    pointer += key

print(plaintext)
print(''.join(ciphertext))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
plaintext = "abcdefghij"

c1 = c2 = ""
for i in range(len(plaintext)//2):
    pointer = 4*i
    c1 += plaintext[pointer:pointer+2]
    c2 += plaintext[pointer+2:pointer+4] 

cipher = c1+c2
```

May not be the most efficient way, but surely works. Add the boundary cases as you want. Runs in O(n)